# Some of the users login screen do not display colors

Tags: terminal, rhel

In my lab I have Redhat Enterprise Linux 5 server.

Users log in through telnet for C programming

Some of the users' login screens display colors, while some other users login screen do not displays colors.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It probably depends on the terminal the users use, and how the respective `TERM` environment variable is set.

Comment: It could also be related to the telnet client they're using, which might be setting the `TERM` variable, and might only support certain terminals.  Also... telnet?  Really?  Why aren't you using ssh?